# Dropdown list of pages to get page id to store in plugin options

Tags: plugin-development, pages, options, dropdown

I need to get a list of all pages in a dropdown list, so I can get the page id of the selected page to store in the options of my plugin.

Right now I have:

```
?>
    <input name='wpplf23_plugin_options[thankyou_page]' type='number' value='<?php if ( ( isset( $options['thankyou_page'] ) ) ) { echo $options['thankyou_page']; } ?>' />
<?php
```

To just store the id manually.

I found this code:

```
$args = array(
    'depth'                 => 0,
    'child_of'              => 0,
    'selected'              => 0,
    'echo'                  => 1,
    'name'                  => 'page_id',
    'id'                    => null, // string
    'class'                 => null, // string
    'show_option_none'      => null, // string
    'show_option_no_change' => null, // string
    'option_none_value'     => null, // string
    );

    wp_dropdown_pages( $args );
```

But I cant work out how to get it to do what I need. How would I go about this?

Thanks for any help you can provide me.

Comment: Wp_dropdown_pages() works well for your case, you need to fill the args with the right value. Ie : selected => get_option('wpplf23_plugin_options['thankyou_page']')

Answer (score 2):

Iam using following code to display a page select dropdown menu on an plugin option page.

If you select an page and save it, the next time you visit the option-site, you will also see which page was saved. (so no more "select page")

You can use the WordPress *selected()* function, you can find more details here:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/selected

```
$options = get_option( 'my_settings' ); ?>

<select name='my_settings[selected_page]'>
    <option value='0'><?php _e('Select a Page', 'textdomain'); ?></option>
    <?php $pages = get_pages(); ?>
    <?php foreach( $pages as $page ) { ?>
        <option value='<?php echo $page->ID; ?>' <?php selected( $options['selected_page'], $page->ID ); ?> ><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></option>
    <?php }; ?>
</select>
```

You just need to get the current-saved-value of the field and than use the WP *selected()* function to compare the current-saved-value with the `$page->ID`.

Maybe this can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code.

```
<select name="page"> 
    <option value=""><?php echo esc_attr( __( 'Select page' ) ); ?></option> 
    <?php 
     $pages = get_pages(); 
     foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
       $option = '<option value="' . $page->ID . '">'.$page->post_title.'</option>';
       echo $option;
     }
    ?>
</select>
```

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: It does get the posts in a list but it doesn't recall it if the option is set it always says "Select page"