# Best way to contruct a global custom field?

Tags: custom-field

I'm trying to think of the best way of being able to edit a certain custom field on a global basis rather than having to go into each post and editing it.

For example an affiliate link custom field which the link will be different for each post/page. It would be better to be able to add all the links to all the pages/posts via a single screen rather than going into each post and adding a link into the field.

I've tried searching for similar solutions but maybe i'm not using the correct terminology to get the desired results.  Any pointers would be highly appreciated .

Comment: How about an options page in your plugin?  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/250753/dropdown-list-of-pages-to-get-page-id-to-store-in-plugin-options

Answer (score 1):

I would use an option page which would show up in the settings.
I used Example #2 from [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages) for a few of my projects.

Then you would use it in your theme like this:

```
$o = get_option('my_option_name'); // how you named the options from Example #2
$field = $o['field_name']; // how you named the field
echo $field;
```